# array type has incomplete element type for pattern matching

Tags: c++, c

This code snippet to produce a pattern.

It is showing "array type has incomplete element type" error! Where it is going wrong?

```
int main(){
int n; 
char a[][];
scanf("%d",&n);

for (int i =0; i<n; i++)
{
for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        if(i>=j)
          a[i][j] = "#";
        else 
            a[i][j]=" ";
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you invest some time to see which line has the error?

Comment: Your array does not have a size.

Comment: @Linus Choudhury  Specify what language is used.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration of an array

```
char a[][];
```

is invalid. The number of elements in each dimension is unknown.

If it is a C program then you could use a variable length array. For example

```
int main( void )
{
    int n; 

    scanf("%d",&n);

    char a[n][n];

    //...
```

Take into account that this condition

```
if(i>=j)
```

does not make sense because the internal loop is defined like

```
for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
              ^^^^
```

that is i is always is greater than j inside the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[][];
```

You don't determine size of array in declaration (this is why error). You need to give size while declaring array.

```
char a[10][10];  // or something
```

If you want give size dynamically use pointers or use VLA's.